# Removing first 2 rows from a .csv file in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, geoip

I am in the beginning stages of making a c# app that downloads a .zip file, extracts a .csv file, and inserts it to a mssql db. Problem is the file contains 2 unnecessary lines at the beginning of the file. Is there a way to strip the 1st 2 lines out? This is geoip data from maxmind.com. Ideally the program would read the .csv, strip out the lines, and resave it. Any advice is welcome. Sample rows below.

```
Copyright (c) 2011 MaxMind Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
"beginIp","endIp","beginIpNum","endIpNum","countryCode","countryName"
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
```

Comment: When you read the file, just add 2 `reader.ReadLine();` statements before beginning to loop over the real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in csv parser in .Net

The following link shows an example
http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/

Just skip the first and second line the same way the example skips the first line.

Answer (score 3):

As @itsme86 said in a comment, you'd probably be best to simply skip over those two lines with

```
reader.ReadLine();
reader.ReadLine();
```

That way, you don't have to worry about copying the full file and resaving it at all. However, if you do want to do that (and I notice you say "Ideally the program would read the .csv, strip out the lines, and resave it"), you can review my answer to a similar question: [Cut and paste line of text from text file c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754658/cut-and-paste-line-of-text-from-text-file-c-sharp/24754940#24754940).

In essence, you'll have to read through the full file and copy it down to another.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(newFile))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(oldFile)) // or you could take this from your `WebResponse` `Stream` if applicable.
{
    reader.ReadLine();
    reader.ReadLine();

    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```