# how to replace a uername and password that is stored in a textfile

Tags: c#, text-files

I am making a quiz application that allows users to register and login in to the application. The details for the users are stored in text files and I have a form which allows the user to change their usernames. I don't know how to override only the usernames in the text-file

my problem is that i don't know how to replace just the password and username for just one user because multiple users can have the same password.I have already tried to look for the solution both in Stack Overflow and the web and I did not find anything similar to my problem. my current code replaces the password for every user with the same password eg multiple users in my text file have password123 for their password.

```
    private void btnUpdateUserDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string oldusername = txtBoxoldUsername.Text;
        string newusername = txtBoxnewUsername.Text;
        string oldpassword= txtBoxoldPassword.Text;
        string newpassword = txtBoxnewPassword.Text;
        string confirmedpassword = txtBoxConfirmedPassword.Text;

        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldusername)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newusername))
           && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldpassword)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newpassword)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(confirmedpassword)))
        {
            if ((!oldusername.Contains("~")) || (!newusername.Contains("~")))
            {
                if (newpassword == confirmedpassword)
                {
                    if (File.Exists("users.txt"))
                    {
                        string[] users = File.ReadAllLines("users.txt");
                        bool userFound = false;

                        foreach (string user in users)
                        {
                            string[] splitDetails = user.Split('~');

                            string username = splitDetails[1];
                            string password = splitDetails[2];

                            if ((txtBoxoldUsername.Text == username) && (txtBoxoldPassword.Text == password))
                            {
                                string text = File.ReadAllText("users.txt");
                                text = text.Replace(oldusername, txtBoxnewUsername.Text).Replace(oldpassword, txtBoxnewPassword.Text);
                                File.WriteAllText("users.txt", text);

                                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Updated Successfully!",
                               "Tas");

                                txtBoxoldUsername.Text = "";
                                txtBoxnewUsername.Text = "";
                                txtBoxoldPassword.Text = "";
                                txtBoxnewPassword.Text = "";
                                txtBoxConfirmedPassword.Text = "";

                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("User details are incorrect",
                                "Incorrect details entered");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No users have been registered", "No users");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("New Passwords don't match",
                                "Incorrect Details");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username must not contain any special characters i.e. ~", "~ entered");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure all data is entered into the fields",
                "Details missing");
        }
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var homeForm = new HomeForm();
        homeForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        homeForm.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you're using `~` to split values in your text file... You just need to `String.Join()` splitDetails, after changing splitDetails[1] to the new value.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___

Comment: So, wait... you're storing logins and passwords as plain text in a text file? Yikes...

Comment: i would check out this link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971008/edit-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-c-sharp

you are going to have to rewrite the file every time

Comment: this is for my A level computing coursework so security isent a concern

Comment: First of all... **What is your problem?** _You never mentioned._ And, what does the file look like? Because you are using the _second_ entry in the split list to compare the name to; the first one would be `splitDetails[0]`. You're also missing the entire case of _adding new_ users; the code you gave only updates ones already in the file.

Comment: this is what my text file looks like  "firstname surname~username~password" i am using the seond entry for my user name because the username comes second

Comment: Edit relevant / missing details into the question, not just as comments