# How to fix missing semicolon error automatically visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automatic-semicolon-insertion

How to fix semicolon missing errors automatically c#.
I have an old project in which semicolon missing in most of the lines. how to include the missing semicolons automatically using visual studio or any other extension

[image]

Comment: Manual fix will be required

Comment: Cannot fix automatically? nearly 1800 lines need to edit

Comment: Add the missing semicolon? Or just write your code correctly in the first place.

Comment: Why would there be an automatic fix for a typo? Think about it.

Comment: Not a typo. It was an old project in vb.net. it happened like this when we converted it to c#

Comment: Use a better tool to convert it to C# then. Evidently the tool you used was utter trash if it didn't add semicolons.

Comment: You could parse all your .cs files and then for each line append a semicolon. It shouldn't show an error if you have a double semicolon on the end of some lines.

Comment: you can read the source file as text and append `;` at the end of line if does not exist. reference code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971052/223752

Comment: [field: AccessedThroughProperty("LayoutControlGroup1")]
 internal virtual LayoutControlGroup LayoutControlGroup1
 {
  get; [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
  set;
 } the project has code like this. all the controls wre like this so we cannot open the designer page. is there a way to replace all the above code like this.  public LayoutControlGroup LayoutControlGroup1;

Comment: @Ibrennan208 In my mind I just see that ending up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3lXa.png) :D

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Definitely :D haha, it would probably result in a similar amount of errors, but still an entertaining idea.

Comment: internal virtual LayoutControlGroup LayoutControlGroup1
 {
  get; [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
  set;
 }

 internal virtual SimpleButton BOK
 {
  [CompilerGenerated]
  get
  {
   return _BOK;
  }
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
  [CompilerGenerated]
  set
  {
   EventHandler value2 = BOK_Click;
   SimpleButton bOK = _BOK;
   if (bOK != null)
   {
    bOK.Click -= value2;
   }
   _BOK = value;
   bOK = _BOK;
   if (bOK != null)
   {
    bOK.Click += value2;
   }
  }
 } the code like this. so i cannot view the designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

- Open up Replace in file.
- Select "Use Regular Expressions".
- Enter ".$" in Search term (no quotes).
- Enter ";" in Replace term (no quotes).

Now do replace single or replace all. Replace all will add too many semicolons (blank lines and comments and all other), but will probably give less than 1800 errors to fix.

Tested it in Visual Studio 17.3.1.